# How to enable javascript in Splash

Tags: javascript, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I have been recently introduced to [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-private-mode-enabled). I'm currently trying to render the webpage of the company that I work at (I prefer not to name the company) in the splash API. When I try to render the page in the Splash API, the html contains a message saying:

```
"Our website can only be used properly with Javascript. 
 Enable Javascript in your browser."
```

At first I didn't understand where this error was coming from, until I disabled the Javascript in my browser and visited the site manually. Without Javascript enabled the same text that I found in the returned Splash html was now visible in my browser:

```
"Our website can only be used properly with Javascript. 
 Enable Javascript in your browser."
```

The weird part is that when I checked to see whether Javascript was enabled in splash by running the following script in the API:

```
function main(splash)
    assert(splash:go('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/is-javascript-enabled'))
    png=splash:png()
    return png
end
```

I got the following image:

[image]

It seems like Javascript is enabled just fine...

**Question:** Why is this website responding to my request as if I have Javascript disabled? How do I fix this problem? Should I add manual commands to enable Splash? (Sorry, I understand that it's annoying that I cannot provide information about the website that I'm trying to visit.)

**Edit:** To see the html in the website that I want to render I'm using the following script:

```
function main(splash, args)
   assert(splash:go(args.url))
   assert(splash:wait(15))
   return {
      html = splash:html(),
      png = splash:png(),
      har = splash:har(),
   }
   end
```

Comment: It’s hard to tell for sure without knowing what the target website is. They are probably not just checking if JavaScript is enabled, regardless of what they say. Or they may be expecting a JavaScript feature not supported by the Splash version that you are using.